# Json parseerror & unexpected token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

Still trying to fix my ajax to work with the controller.
Now I get this error message:

```
response SyntaxError: Unexpected token j ,  xhr[object Object] ,  STATUS parsererror
```

config.routes

```
resources :books do 
    member do 
      get '/last_chapter/', to: 'chapters#last_chapter', as: 'last_chapter', defaults: { format: 'json' }
    end
    resources :chapters
  end
```

chapter controller

```
def last_chapter
        @last_chapter = Chapter.order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json
        end
    end
```

last_chapter.json

```
json.extract! @last_chapter, :id, :title, :characters, :created_at, :updated_at
```

script.js

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '/books/103/last_chapter.json',
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('JAAAA ENDELIG FUNKER DET');
        $("body").html(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, response) {
        console.log('response ' + response +  ' ,  xhr' + xhr +  ' ,  ' + 'STATUS ' + status)}
    });
```

Feel like I have tried everything. Please let me know if you need anymore information! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in the routes. Here is what I would do:

```
resources :books do
  get :last_chapter, on: :member
end
```

**books_controller.rb**

```
def last_chapter
  @last_chapter = Book.find(params[:id]).chapters.last
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render json: { does_it_work: :yes }
    end
  end
end
```

I assume the following model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :chapters
end
```

Comment: How would you do the url for the ajax? For now it can't find "/last_chapter" because I need the last chapter id.

Comment: I would leave the ajax call as it is. What's the point of `last_chapter` action then if you need to know the id of it? You need to provide a `book_id`, and then this action should return the last chapter of this book!

Comment: Also, when I add in the url manually (with the chapter id) like this.
 url: '/books/103/chapters/206/last_player.json',


 I get this error:
` Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://kchdfagjljmhgapoonapmfngpadcjkhk/js/scripts.js:24:42)
    at chrome-extension://kchdfagjljmhgapoonapmfngpadcjkhk/js/scripts.js:11:21`

Comment: If I leave the url as it was it gives me this error:
404 (Not Found)

Comment: Do you have a book with id `103`?

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that because of the routing you suggested. the Url for /latest_chapter is now: /books/:book_id/chapters/:chapter_id/last_chapter

Instead of
/books/:book_id/last_chapter

Comment: You're right, my bad. I corrected the routes above.

Comment: I tried the new method and moved the json to the books view and I still get 404 (Not Found) :/

Comment: Now the error went back to this: 
extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://kchdfagjljmhgapoonapmfngpadcjkhk/js/scripts.js:24:42)
    at chrome-extension://kchdfagjljmhgapoonapmfngpadcjkhk/js/scripts.js:11:21

:(

Comment: That has nothing to do with your code though, but with the google chrome extension you're using...How about testing from the command-line? `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://hostname/resource`

Comment: Oh!  that's not good :/ How can I fix that ? Anyway, the commandline generates ALOT of codes, looks like javascript and css and a little bit of html. Don't know what it is for though, I have not written it.

Comment: It's probably an error. If you save it in an html file and open it in your browser, it should be clearer.

Comment: Aha. Didn't say much. Gem.paths = { 'GEM_PATH' => [Bundler.bundle_path.to_s, *Gem.path].uniq.join(Gem.path_separator) }
    gem 'spring', match[1]
    require 'spring/binstub'#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
Response

Headers:

None
That's it .